# Simple Python program to connect to a secure wifi network with user input credentials

Tags: python, security, networking, windows-7, wifi

My question I guess is: Is this possible without shelling out to command line and without 3rd party Python packages? I can't seem to find any native Python commands to manipulate or configure a wireless network connection. I know there are already built-in 'netsh wlan' commands in Windows 7, but would rather this all be in python. I am also confused by the logistics of this operation. With the netsh stuff, you still are required to have a wireless profile xml file specified in the command. My current image doesn't have any wireless profiles and I do not really understand the purpose of that if you are connecting to a brand new network. Why is this not automatically generated when you connect?

---

A little bit about the network

Network type: Infrastructure

Authentication: WPA2-Enterprise

Encryption: CCMP

---

The ultimate goal is to have a script that my users can just launch, put in their credentials, and never see the multiple Windows dialogues while doing so. I'm not asking for someone to write this for me. That's what I'm suppose to do. I just need to know if anyone has successfully done something like this in strictly Python or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Well it seems kind of obvious to me that the profile is necessary because clearly you have to specify somewhere to which AP to connect, what connection type to use, etc. And a short google search leads to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369853(v=vs.85).aspx) which affirms that assumption. Just use the windows tools and provide them the profile which you can easily generate automatically anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Python standard library doesn't ship with any functionality to control platform-specific functionality like wireless adapters.  You have to invoke the tools shipped with the platform, find some 3rd party libraries that control this functionality, or write your own such libraries.